# crystal reports "show sql query" - how accurate is it?

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports-xi

The business is wanting new crystal reports to be built within designer only and less database objects, like procedures and views. The aim being for future transparent maintenance. But this is making tasks more difficult for me.  I am wondering as to the accuracy of Show SQL Query?  I have little control over the actual sql query being run on the server and feel like I am flying blind.

Obviously it makes more sense to build as much of the logic server-side but trying to keep client happy.  My latest foray highlights some glaring issues with Show SQL Query:

1. Multiple table hits not showing! eg: 3 different tables needing to
   hit the same base table. I have linked up the base table multiple
   times and changed the naming to suit.  But the query as shown by
   Show SQL Query only mentions one of the 3 tables!  Even though the
   report is working off all 3 repeated tables just fine.
2. Nested logic is promlematic.  I have to copy and paste into a
   text editor, do a bit of formatting to make the sql readable and even
   then it just doesn't look right logic wise.

Is there another way to keep everyone happy?

Comment: Is there a way to keep everyone happy? Depends whether they will see reason, i.e. understand it's more of a maintenance liability to build horrible workarounds inside the crystal reports editor instead of reusable sql logic in the database. Perhaps you could find the worst example of doing it in this way and present it to your boss in a constructive fashion.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the morale boost!  Yes I like your idea.  Its just a matter of time and everything will be up for discussion then.